# NetLogo: Run 2 different models in one using chooser

Tags: model, netlogo

I am using NetLogo to code a model based on economic segregation. Within this model I want to provide 2 different models. One that shows Gentrification and one that shows segregation based on economic status and race. I was able to use the chooser to have both models work, however I was wondering if there is a way to change the displays, graphs, and/or buttons that appear based on which model-version is chosen?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no built in extension that allows for widgets (e.g. plots, buttons, switches, etc.) to be switched in and out programatically.

However, you could use the [LevelSpace Extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/ls.html) to open one model or another based on your chooser. Check out the `Parent Model Example` and `Model Visualizer Example` models in the Models Library to see some examples.

Comment: xWidgets is not built in, but it is robust. It only allows input widgets though